# update all value dataframe Pandas by concat the old value by another value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am beginner on python and pandas. I am trying to update the value of dataframe. 
I have

```
    Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

and I would like to change the dataframe to

```
    Name
1   A_1
2   B_1
3   C_1
```

add "_1" to all values

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["A", "B", "C"]})
df["Name"] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: str(x)+"_1")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name
0  A_1
1  B_1
2  C_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest without and extra cost with inbuilt feature:

**Using `dataFrame.add`**

```
>>> df
  Name
0    A
1    B
2    C

>>> df = df.Name.add("_1")
>>> df
0    A_1
1    B_1
2    C_1
```

**Using `map`:**

dictionary of replacement values into the Series replace method:

```
>>> df
  Name
0    A
1    B
2    C


>>> df['Name'] = df['Name'].map({'A': 'A_1', 'B': 'B_1', 'C': 'C_1'})
>>> df
  Name
0  A_1
1  B_1
2  C_1
```

**Using `replace` method:**

```
>>> df.Name.replace(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A_1', 'B_1', 'C_1'], inplace=True)
>>> df
  Name
0  A_1
1  B_1
2  C_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string concat:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name']+'_1'

print(df)
  Name
1  A_1
2  B_1
3  C_1
```

Comment: found more simpler first time used `df.Name.add("_1")` :-)